# Automation of docker pull via scala

Tags: java, linux, scala, docker

Env: AMI RHEL FEDORA

I wrote a script file to pull latest image from private repo / registry. When execute the script from bash file it works fine.

I tried to do the same from scala (sampleservice)

```
val p = Process( path+ "execFile.sh" ,
      Some(new File( path + execndir)))
```

Note :  execFile.sh   permission is root  as the application is installed via sudo yum install

I get

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

I even add the user to docker grp. How can over some this issue.

Comment: Don't you have to quote strings in Scala? Shouldn't that be `val p = Process (path + "execFile.sh", Some(new File(path + execndir)))` ?

Comment: Sorry its typo. In my code i pass it as String Process (path + "execFile.sh"...

Comment: Could you show us the source code of `execFile.sh`?

Comment: do you have docker-machine running?

Comment: yes installed.  Pulling image from private-docker-hub.my.space/pogo/the-ers
Error: image pogo/the-ers:2.0-SNAPSHOT not found.   In the same script i am able to pull postgres.9.4.5  Note: the private registry got pogo/the-ers:2.0-SNAPSHOT.   At the same time when I try the docker pull from command line. docker happily pulls down the image to local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys

$ sudo docker login https://

worked

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

When running sudo docker login credentials are saved in /root/.docker/config.json.

This helped me to pull images.